# Почему сортировка не работает?

Tags: php

Почему сортировка не работает?

```
<?php
$directory = './img/tesla_model_s'; //название папки с изображениями
$allowed_types=array('jpg','jpeg'); //разрешеные типы изображений
$file_parts=array();
  $ext='';
  $title='';
  $i=0;
//пробуем открыть папку
  $dir_handle = @opendir($directory) or die("There is an error with your image directory!");
while ($file = readdir($dir_handle))    //поиск по файлам
  {
  if($file=='.' || $file == '..') continue;
  $file = array($file);
sort($file);
foreach ($file as $file) { 
 echo '<div id="container"><img src="js/blank.gif" data-src="'.$directory.'/'.$file.'" /></div>';

 $i++;  
    }
    }
closedir($dir_handle);  //закрыть папку
?>
```

Comment: Почему она должна у вас работать, если в массиве всегда 1 элемент?

Comment: [Справочник по функции readdir](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.readdir.php)

Comment: Прошу уточнить как исправить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте функцию [scandir()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.scandir.php), которая вернет вам список файлов и каталогов, расположенных по указанному пути в виде массива. Массив по умолчанию будет уже отсортирован по алфавиту. Этот массив в цикле и перебирайте для вывода информации.

Comment: Прошу уточнить как исправить? Пытался делать разными путями. Максимум, что получалось это вывод:    img_1.jpg, img_10.jpg, а должно img_1.jpg, img_2.jpg....

Comment: Отсортируйте массив с помощью функции natcasesort() http://php.net/manual/ru/function.natcasesort.php

Comment: Так или нет?   `$file = array($file);
natcasesort($file);
foreach ($file as $file) { 
 echo '<div id="container"><img src="js/blank.gif" data-src="'.$directory.'/'.$file.'" /></div>';`

Comment: Почему у вас тут `$file = array($file);` и тут `foreach ($file as $file)` одна и та же переменная выступает как массив и как его элемент?

Comment: Спасибо! Вопрос решен.

Answer (score 2):

Простой набросок я конечно напишу, чтобы вы смогли посмотреть и разобраться в своих ошибках. Но подобные вопросы, которые по факту являются требованием написать пример за вас здесь не приветствуются. По коду ниже, не проверял его на работоспособность и синтаксические ошибки и вообще корректность подобного подхода. Только подправил ваш "код".

```php
<?php
$directory = './img/tesla_model_s'; //название папки с изображениями
$allowed_types=array('jpg','jpeg'); //разрешеные типы изображений
$file_parts=array();
  $ext='';
  $title='';
  $i=0;
//пробуем открыть папку
  $dir_handle = @opendir($directory) or die("There is an error with your image directory!");
$files=array();
while ($file = readdir($dir_handle))    //поиск по файлам
  {
  if($file=='.' || $file == '..') continue;
  array_push($files,$file);
  }
  sort($files);
foreach ($files as $file) { 
 echo '<div id="container"><img src="js/blank.gif" data-src="'.$directory.'/'.$file.'" /></div>';

 $i++;  

    }
closedir($dir_handle);  //закрыть папку
?>
```

Comment: Спасибо. Немного не так. Я уже писал, вывод происходит: img_1.jpg, img_10.jpg, а должно img_1.jpg, img_2.jpg...Почему так происходит?

Comment: Так и должно быть при сортировке строки. Строка сортирует не цифры в конце названия, а алфавитный порядок именно поэтому цифры рассматриваются не как число, а как буквы алфавита. В комментарии ниже вам предложили использовать вместо **sort** функцию **natcasesort** - это решение вашей проблемы.

Comment: Спасибо, действительно решило вопрос!